# Type error while using scikit-learns SimpleImputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror

This code is for data preprocessing that I am learning in an online course of ML.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #pyplot is a sublibrary of matplotlib
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
Y = dataset.iloc[:,-1]


from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan,strategy = 'mean',verbose = 0) 
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

But it is giving this Type error: unhashable type: 'slice' .
Please help me with this.

[image: The image for the same is also attached.]

Comment: it is better to add some sample dataset when you post this kind of question.otherwise it is hard to reproduce.

Comment: Actually I am a beginner so I do not know exactly how to describe the problem and what data should I provide. So I will keep in mind this. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: sample data of data.csv .so anyone can reproduce the question and answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

X is a dataframe and you can't access like X[:,1:3].you should use iloc.
Try this

```
imputer = imputer.fit(X.iloc[:,1:3])
X.iloc[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X.iloc[:,1:3])
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you please elaborate it a bit or suggest any good source so that I can grab things?

Answer (score 0):

I would also advise to make use of `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` and `sklearn.compose .ColumnTransformer` make these preprocessing transformation if your final goal is to predict: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-mixed-types-py